# How do I print and select numbers from an int[] array with streams and lambdas

Tags: java, arrays, lambda, integer

My goal is to read and select numbers from an array, then take those which are greater than 0 and print them out
this is the code i have as example:

```
public class LambdaTest {
    private int[] num = new int[10];

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LambdaTest test = new LambdaTest();
        //Lista de números a ordenar
        test.num[0] = 5;
        test.num[1] = -6;
        test.num[2] = 7;
        test.num[3] = 23;
        test.num[4] = -1;
        test.num[5] = 55;
        test.num[6] = 78;
        test.num[7] = 45;
        test.num[8] = 31;
        test.num[9] = -67;
        //Proceso normal
        for (int i=0; i<test.num.length; i++){
            if (test.num[i]>=0){
                System.out.println(test.num[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But with lambda expressions and streams, thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do

```
Arrays.stream(test.num).filter(n -> n >= 0).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: That's it!!
I've got a question if you don't mind me asking. Where could I learn how to use Lambdas and Streams correctly, I saw lots of videos and read lots of PDFs but is impossible for me to get it rigth. If you could recommend me something i would appreciate it, thank you ;)

Comment: It sounds as though you have plenty of tutorials but just need to practice on typical scenarios...

Comment: I'll keep trying then, thak you!!